# TreeView detect node select but not when checking or unchecking

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have an event that fires using the [AfterSelect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect?view=net-5.0) Event, and this works just fine, but I do not want this event to fire if the user either checks or unchecks the checkbox of this or any node in the tree. Alternatively, the event can fire, but then I need to know inside the event if it was fired as a result of a check or uncheck of the checkbox.  I have tried using NodeMouseClick instead but I get the same unwanted result, and I have also tried removing the event handler using BeforeCheck and adding it back using AfterCheck, like so:

```
private void MyTree_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyTree.AfterSelect -= new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.MyTree_AfterSelect);
}

private void MyTree_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyTree.AfterSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.MyTree_AfterSelect);
}

private void MyTree_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    ShowMyInfo(e.Node);
}
```

but the AfterSelect event still fires.

I cannot rely on `AfterCheck` because then it won't fire if you simply select the node.  I also cannot rely on checking if `e.Node.Selected == true`, because the node might already be checked, and I want the event to fire if the node is in fact deliberately selected.

Is there any event handler I can use that will trigger only if a node is SELECTED, and not CHECKED or UNCHECKED, or any way I can detect if a node that's just been selected has been checked or unchecked.

Using Visual Studio 2019 with a C# WinForms .NET Framework application.

Comment: IIRC, `AfterSelect` is not raised when a User checks/unchecks a node. Only if/when the node is clicked, not the CheckBox.

Comment: As Jimi said. That never happens unless you have some code that selects the node regardless it is checked or not. Like selecting a node on `MouseClick` or `NodeMouseClick` or elsewhere. For now, check the [TreeViewEventArgs.Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treevieweventargs.action?view=net-5.0) property in the `AfterSelect` event and `return;` if it returns `TreeViewAction.Unknown` and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jimi and @dr.null have pointed out, I am using the right event after all.  AfterSelect will not fire just because you checked or unchecked the checkbox.

The problem that I had was that I have code that will select a node if you right click it (right clicking does not automatically select a node).

Old Code:

```
    private void MyTree_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTree.SelectedNode = MyTree.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
    }
```

New Code:

```
    private void MyTree_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) MyTree.SelectedNode = MyTree.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
    }
```

I was inadvertently firing off my own event because I did not check for which mouse button was clicked on the MouseDown event.  Thank you for the help!